Finding the MLE using a contour plot
When finding the MLE of something using a log-likelihood contour plot, is the MLE in the middle of the middle ring?

Definitely not, because middle rings don't necessarily exist and there can be many of them.

Compare it with a contour plot of a mountain and finding the peak or highest point.

Image Source: Wikipedia Commons
And compare this to a cardboard topographic model like this one from https://www.geoblox.com/topo.html

The contour lines on the 2d map represent the layers of cardboard that you use in such model.
Here are examples of both a surface plot and a contour in one view (they are not likelihood plots, I don't have examples for that):


So the peak will be on the last/highest cardboard slice and surrounded by a contour line, but be aware of the following:
Exact location

in the middle of the middle ring?

It doesn't have to be exactly the middle; it can also be somewhere else inside the ring. See for instance Afkins hill in the terrain map above, where one side is very steep and the other side not. There you see that the peak is closer to the steeper part.
The example below from How to compute the gradient for a separable nonlinear least-squares problem? shows an extreme case where the contour is not a nice round ring shape and the peak is at a far edge of the surrounded area.

Multiple local peaks
In the terrain map there are several local peaks and they each have a ring shape surrounding them. The ring shape indicates a local extreme point (which, btw, can also be a minimum), and it doesn't have to be the MLE.
An example of a likelihood function with multiple modes is on this website in the question Bayesian inference with false models: to what does it converge?

The Cauchy distribution can also cause these multiple modes, see this related question Examples of distribution for which first-order condition is not enough for MLE
MLE at or near the boundary
If the MLE is at or near a boundary for the parameters, then you don't get this ring shape either.
MLE at infinity
The MLE, if you allow it in the definition, can be at infinity. This can happen with logistic regression and a description of such case is in: MLE in a logistic regression model

This is a nice way to explain contour (+1). However, a request, you may say, it would also be appreciable if you might be able to make a likelihood plot of a toy data to show what you already said using the above contour.

Amazing answer ! !  +1
